# How to exchange records values?

Tags: sql

How to update all records with `role = 1` to value `2` and records with `role = 2` to value `1` ?

```
  login   | role
----------+------
 john     |    1
 anne     |    2
 adam     |    1
 robert   |    1
 katie    |    1
 bob      |    2
 tom      |    2
 ...many records with 1 and 2 values
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table

SET role = CASE role
               WHEN 1 THEN 2
               ELSE 1
           END

WHERE role = 1 OR role = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [table]
SET role = CASE role
               WHEN 1 THEN 2
               ELSE 1
           END
WHERE role = 1 OR role = 2;
```